# Display username password

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Now that SoftLayer has deprecated updatePassword, I am re designing our approach of username passwords. I am using SoftLayer_Account::getUsers method to retrieve a username profile and checking the password expiration date. If the password has expired I am going to use this new marvelous SoftLayer_User_Customer::initiatePortalPasswordChange method to change it, unless you can direct me to another way to change a user password. If the password has not expired, How can I retrieve the current password of a username profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in [Portal Control](https://control.softlayer.com/) in login screen >> **Reset Password**

This is the only way to change it,

Any update or comment you can send an email to: PortalFeedback@softlayer.com

Comment: How can I retrieve the existing password for the user profile?

Comment: There is no way to retrieve it, the only way is **Reset Password**

Comment: These new changes are a big surprise which are breaking procedures and scripts for us.   I know,    "Any update or comment you can send an email to: PortalFeedback@softlayer.com "

Comment: Yep, this is a big change, but I think the goal is to improve the security. My apologies for the inconveniences.