# SoftLayer api call initiatePortalPasswordChange fails

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

This API call does nothing but tell you call them over the phone.

```
>>> client['User_Customer'].initiatePortalPasswordChange(username)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    client['User_Customer'].initiatePortalPasswordChange(username)
  File "/Users/p/.VirtualEnvs/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 373, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/p/.VirtualEnvs/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 341, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/p/.VirtualEnvs/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 237, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/Users/p/.VirtualEnvs/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 187, in __call__
    raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): User needs to contact revenue services in order to reset your password. Please contact 1-866-325-0045 Option 3 in order to reset your password.
```

It was frustrating enough when `updatePassword` was deprecated and broke our automation, as discussed by others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246936/display-username-password).  But it is even more frustrating when the watered down api call to simply initiate a password reset tells you call call them over the phone.  Seriously?  SoftLayer is deconstructing their api, one call at a time, in order to stifle automation.

Can someone tell me why the `initiatePortalPasswordChange` api call won't work?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is the place for questions about API desing, I think it may due to security reasons, but better send a email here PortalFeedback@softlayer.com about this.

Regards

Comment: I hate that as a SoftLayer customer, I have to ask about API issues publicly here on Stack Overflow rather than via a private SoftLayer ticket.  However, on several occasions, I was specifically told by SoftLayer staff at the end of a long well-detailed ticket, that API questions should be posted here on SO instead.  Asking via a ticket has proven time and again, to be an exercise in futility.  My hope is that SoftLayer's API experts (which according to SoftLayer are here on SO) will respond to my API issue here.